# Primary key column with Foreign key reference to itself

Tags: sql-server

I came across this T-SQL code in a client's database today:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Dates
(
    MarketDate date,
    PRIMARY KEY (MarketDate), 
    FOREIGN KEY (MarketDate) REFERENCES dbo.Dates (MarketDate)
)
```

It is unclear to me what purpose can be served by allowing the primary key column to have a foreign key relationship back to itself. Naturally I have deleted the relationship.

Would this foreign key have any effect at all? Is there ever a use case which would justify using it? If not then why would SQL Server permit such a relationship.

Comment: This table does not look like regular accounting storage, it's more likely a persistent _calendar_ for programming purposes. I'd first ask the developer. This could be a trick described by @S.Karras to avoid any editing, but it does not seem workable to me.

Comment: If you find out can you update your answer please? This one is interesting and I've love to find out the developers reason. Cheers!

Comment: @DaveBrown: in addition to TRUNCATE, DELETE and UPDATE are also allowed (at least on SQL 2012).  I agree--interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can imagine is that the creator of the table wanted to disallow the use of TRUNCATE TABLE statements against the Dates table.

Comment: I wondered but I've just created it and it allows Truncate Table with 1, 10 and 100 entries in it. Have to admit I'm surprised the engine is advanced enough to know truncate table is ok here. Weird.